# class point to a class c++

Tags: c++, class, struct

In C, a struct can have a member that point to itself. I want to write a C++ version of this. Can I define a class `kd_node_t` and inside it has a member `class  kd_node_t *left, *right` ? Thank you

```
struct kd_node_t{
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    struct kd_node_t *left, *right;
};
```

Comment: Did you try before asking?

Comment: @Amit Yes I did but got errors

Comment: can you? you just did it

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: I will use struct for node and class for the tree. Thank you guys. @tobi303

Comment: I am sorry but this doesnt make sense, there is conceptually no difference between a `struct` and a `class` (the only difference is struct members and base classes default to public while for classes the defaul it private)

Comment: but for a binary tree, i want a struct to save each node, while for the entire tree, it contains the nodes and the methods, such as create tree, delete tree, search a node,etc. if I use class for every node, then it means every node will have those methods, and it is a waste of space. So I decide to treat node and tree differently. @tobi303

Comment: methods don't take up any space in the object

Comment: agree with @M.M plus still there is conceptually no difference between class and struct (apart from the minor difference I mentioned before)

Comment: Oh, @M.M, so I can use class for this? It won't take up any more space than using struct? Thank you!@tobi303

Comment: you dont believe me, do you? `struct foo : base {void bar();}` is 100% equivalent to : `class foo : public base {public: void bar();}` its just a matter of convenience of typing or convention, usually simple structures with only public members have the keyword `struct` while anything more complicated goes with keyword `class`

Comment: In C++ (but not C) you can just say `kd_node_t *left, *right` without the `struct` (or `class`) prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you did specify `class` keyword before member pointer declaration. This works perfectly for me.

```
#define MAX_DIM 10

class kd_node_t{
// members must be public before usage as structure
public:
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    kd_node_t *left, *right;
};
```